How to change the shape of a div yet keep its functionality as a normal div?
I saw the below design and would like to implement something similar in my web application, but how do I make the div tilted on the top (as shown in the image)?

My output:



<div class="" style="height: 100vh; background-color: white"></div>
<div class="" style="height: 100vh;position: relative; border: 2px solid black;">
  <div class="" style="height: calc(50% + 2rem);background-color: white;"></div>
  <div class="" style="height: calc(50% - 2rem);background-color: blue;"></div>
  <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 9; transform: translateY(-50%); transform: rotate(-2deg); text-align: center;width: 100%; background-color: yellow; height: 4rem">WELCOME TO OUR WEBSITE</h1>
</div>
<div class="" style="height: 100vh; background-color: blue"></div>



I also tried tailwind skew and transform rotate but there was no luck I got a horizontal scrollbar and there is white space after turning the div
Expected:
Similar to the first image I posted, I want to make a proper responsive tilted div using tailwind. It should be full width tilted on the top with a two-tone color and a straight bottom.

put it inside another div that has overflow: hidden

thanks for the quick reply @tacoshy but that did not work and is not responsive. Also I am trying to achieve this via tailwind could you please suggest a tailwind approach?

You should add all the details and attempts inside your question

the start using tailwind in your example. Nothing you posted so far indicates a tailwind relevance. Why should overflow: hidden not be responsive?

@DarkBee you have been on ghost mode.  Asker: you can use Vanilla see docs https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/

@WildThing Make a parent div position:relative  and padding-top to cover the slant part of the title, then apply  position:absolute; left:0; right:0;'  and   top: to-relevant to the height of the div;` to the slant div.

The requirement needs more specifying. What do you want it to look like on different aspect-ratios - is it important to maintain the same angle? If so, is the start distance from the top on the left or on the right the important one to keep constant (in relative terms) or is it important to have the banner rotated about its center and that to be at a defined distance down? Or are the relative ditances of the left and right ends from the top the things that are to remain constant? (in which case the angle will differ).

This turned out to be more difficult than I anticipated. I found only one relatively responsive approach.
There are two challenges:

overflow: hidden cannot be applied exclusively to the x-axis or y-axis. If overflow: hidden is applied in one direction, it hides overflow in both directions.
After rotating at a fixed angle, there will be different amounts of empty space depending on the viewport width. This space needs to be filled.

Solutions:

For the first issue, use overflow: clip to hide overflow in only the x direction.
For the second issue, define another element to fill the empty space. However, the height of this element needs to be estimated in advance based on the rotation angle, as being too long or too short could cause a visual overflow effect.



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex min-h-dvh flex-col justify-center">
  <article class="relative mx-8 my-32 overflow-x-clip">
    <header class="inset-x-0 bottom-full min-h-12 w-[200%] origin-bottom-left -rotate-6 bg-lime-400">
      <div class="w-1/2">
        <!-- header content -->
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center py-2 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold uppercase">Welcome to our website</div>
      </div>
      <div class="absolute inset-0 top-full h-96 bg-red-500"></div>
    </header>
    <section class="relative h-96 bg-blue-500">
      <!-- main content -->
      <p class="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-3xl font-bold text-white">Your content here</p>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>



Demo on Tailwind Play.
In the example, I used red and blue to differentiate between the filling elements and the main content. In actual use, they should be set to the same color.

why cannot overflow: hidden not be applied to a single axis? what do you believe overflow-x and overflow-y is supposed to do?

@tacoshy At first, I thought the same, but after trying it, it really didn’t work. The article I mentioned in my answer discusses this, specifically in the paragraph right before the first CodePen example.
You can also try changing overflow-x-clip in my answer to overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-visible, but it doesn’t work.
If I missed something, please let me know.

@KarsonJo this is amazing! thank you for the detailed explanation. I did not know overflow: clip existed, this is the way to do it. it is responsive as well!

You need to combine transformations: the translateY(-50%) and rotate(-2deg). Below code will help you
<div class="" style="height: 100vh; background-color: white"></div>
<div class="" style="height: 100vh;position: relative; border: 2px solid black;">
  <div class="" style="height: calc(50% + 2rem);background-color: white;"></div>
  <div class="" style="height: calc(50% - 2rem);background-color: blue;"></div>
  <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 9; transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-2deg); text-align: center; width: 100%; background-color: yellow; height: 4rem; padding-top: 20px;">WELCOME TO OUR WEBSITE</h1>
</div>
<div class="" style="height: 100vh; background-color: blue"></div>

